# Where to put google-services.json file in an expo project?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I am creating a project in Expo and want to add firebase as a real time database. and as i was following the firebase docs. there is a google-services.json file which need to placed somewhere my expo project. But i can't seem to find the path(location) where to place it.
can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 10):

You can keep it in root or in any other folder also.

You just need to make sure that you give correct path in `app.json` file inside `googleServicesFile` key

```
{
  "expo": {
    ....
    ...
    "android": {
      // The package you used with your Firebase app
      "package": "example.expo.googlesignin",
      // Optional path to the Android file generated by Firebase
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
    }
  }
}
```

Find more on [official document](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/)